# Sh’mini atzeret Halacha

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, chagim-holidays, shmini-atzeres

Do all the Halachic implications  of Yom Tov  apply to Sh’mini atzeret (in Eretz Yisrael), or is it considered like Chol Hamoed or some other category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rambam, [Laws of Rest on Holidays 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Rest_on_a_Holiday.1.1)

> שֵׁשֶׁת יָמִים הָאֵלּוּ שֶׁאֲסָרָן הַכָּתוּב בַּעֲשִׂיַּת מְלָאכָה שֶׁהֵן רִאשׁוֹן וּשְׁבִיעִי שֶׁל פֶּסַח וְרִאשׁוֹן וּשְׁמִינִי שֶׁל חַג הַסֻּכּוֹת וּבְיוֹם חַג הַשָּׁבוּעוֹת וּבְאֶחָד לַחֹדֶשׁ הַשְּׁבִיעִי הֵן הַנִּקְרָאִין יָמִים טוֹבִים. וּשְׁבִיתַת כֻּלָּן שָׁוָה שֶׁהֵן אֲסוּרִין בְּכָל מְלֶאכֶת עֲבוֹדָה חוּץ מִמְּלָאכָה שֶׁהִיא לְצֹרֶךְ אֲכִילָה
> The six days on which the Torah forbade work are the first and seventh days of Pesach, the first and eighth days of the festival of Sukkot, the festival of Shavuot, and the first day of the seventh month. They are referred to as holidays. The [obligation to] rest is the same on all these days; it is forbidden to perform all types of servile labor, with the exception of those labors necessary for [the preparation of] food